# How to obtain the list the current instantiated objects for a given class in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, reflection, objective-c-runtime

Since class_poseAs(..) is deprecated in Objective-C 2.0, I need to find another way to change the class of an object at runtime. I've found I can change an object's class using object_setClass(..). My problem now is **finding all the current instances of a given class** in order to update them.

A solution would be to maintain a global dictionary of the instances I want to potentially update, but I'd like to know whether there's already a way to obtain such a collection from the reflective api.

I checked [Apple's Runtime reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) and I cannot find anything useful. Updating just the method of a class with *method_exchangeImplementations(..)* is not a solution for me since I want to be able to reuse the *old* implementation by using *super*.

Answer (score 2):

Generally if you want to exchange the implementation of various methods in a particular class for your own, you'd use the [method_exchangeImplementations()](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/method_exchangeImplementations) function in the Objective-C 2.0 runtime. (You'll need to `#import objc/runtime.h`). This is far simpler than trying to swap out the actual class, as `poseAsClass:` is deprecated and unavailable in the 64-bit runtime.

Comment: As I mention in the third paragraph, I really need to change the whole class and not only the methods. I want to take advantage of the OO-dispatch mechanism to reuse the original code. (The new class for the object would be a subclass or the original one).